# Solving a well known transcendental equation

Tags: equation-solving, complex

Evaluating

```
Solve[E^(n t) == Cos[t] + n Sin[t], n]
```

does not produce a solution for $n$. What method should be used to solve for the value of $n$?

Comment: Why are you using curly braces "`{}`"?

Comment: Thanks,changed it..

Comment: Are you looking for a solution that is valid for all values of `t`

Comment: Yes.wish to be able to include all solutions in a single plot if possible.

Answer (score 2):

Have you given

```
Reduce[E^(n t) == Cos[t] + n Sin[t], n]
```

a try? Since you have not given any constraints on 't', Reduce finds all the possible solutions of n with different constraints on 't'.

Comment: seems to Enlarge, not Reduce.

Comment: It provides all the possible solutions it can calculate, separated by ||. For example, `(C[1] | C[2]) \[Element] 
  Integers && ((t != 0 && t == 2 \[Pi] C[2] && 
    n == (2 I \[Pi] C[1])/t)` is one solution.

Comment: Thanks for editing the braces, I just copied and pasted from your question without seeing the typo. I wonder if you found what you were looking for.

Comment: I did not quite understand why $t$ should not be altogether excluded from the general solution.

Comment: @Narasimham Because $t$ is an unknown parameter?!

Comment: That agreed, but how can we graph  *all  the solutions as a function of $t,$* with constant $ i=\sqrt {-1}$ as a special case that of a constant.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101117/discussion-between-narasimham-and-debsuvra).